# How to construct strings from lines in files, and then files basing on lines in the resultant file?

Tags: bash

I am starting to write my first big bash script, and I'm trying to approach one problem.

I have a file: `packagesList.txt` that contains the names of oracle Packages I need to run through sqlplus. The file looks like this:

```
ORACLETASK1
ORACLETASK2
```

Etc.

The folder Configuration contains files named after the packages. Their names look this way: `ORACLETASK1-test.txt`, `ORACLETASK2-test.txt` and their content looks exactly like this:

```
ORACLETASK1FUNCTION1(PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2)
ORACLETASK1FUNCTION1(PARAMETER3, PARAMETER4)
```

The same goes for the `ORACLETASK2`:

```
ORACLETASK2FUNCTION1(PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2)
ORACLETASK2FUNCTION1(PARAMETER3, PARAMETER4)
```

Now - what I need to do is to generate a file (in a loop) `ORACLETASK1-run.conf` that will look like this:

```
ORACLETASK1.ORACLETASK1FUNCTION1(PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2)
ORACLETASK1.ORACLETASK1FUNCTION1(PARAMETER3, PARAMETER4)
ORACLETASK2.ORACLETASK2FUNCTION1(PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2)
ORACLETASK2.ORACLETASK2FUNCTION1(PARAMETER3, PARAMETER4)
```

Finallz, I need to generate (in a loop) a series of sql files for each line in the `ORACLETASK1-run.conf` file that will look like this:

```
QUESTION UNRELATED SET AND CLEAR COMMANDS GO HERE

VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR;
```

**AND THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE GOES HERE**

```
EXEC :RC := ORACLETASK1.ORACLETASK1FUNCTION1(PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2);
```

The rest of the file

```
SPOOL SOME_FILE_NAME_I_DONT_KNOW_HOW_TO_NAME_IT_YET.TXT
PRINT RC;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT;
```

Maybe this question is a bit general, but I'm looking for any clues that could lead me to making this script work...

Comment: clues: reading files http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1757-how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line and manipulating lines in stream http://rute.2038bug.com/node11.html.gz and concatenating the output in a file https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/cat.1.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you moving in the right direction:

```
CONFIGDIR="/path/to/config/files"

while read -r line ; do
  while read -r config ; do
    echo "$line.$config" >> "ORACLETASK1-run.conf"
  done < "$CONFIGDIR/$line-test.txt"
done < packagesList.txt

while read -r line ; do
  sqlfile=$(echo $line | sed -r 's/(.*\..*)\((.*), *(.*)\)/\1.\2.\3/'
  cat << _EOCFG_ >> "$sqlfile.sql"
VARIABLE RC REFCURSOR;
EXEC :RC := $line; 
SPOOL SOME_FILE_NAME_I_DONT_KNOW_HOW_TO_NAME_IT_YET.TXT
PRINT RC;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT;
_EOCFG_
done < ORACLETASK1-run.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to read the file where your scripts is and a subfolder named Configuration.

You need to do something like

```
for i in *.txt Configuration/*.txt; do
    [ -e "$i" ] || continue
    filename=$(echo "$i" | cut -d- -f1)
    while IFS= read -r aline; do 
      #do something
    done < $i
done
```

The cut command, is an example to how to get the first part of a file like "ORACLETASK1-test.txt", the result will be "ORACLETASK1" because of the param **"-d-"**.

You can work on each line of each file where the comment is. That's where you put the logic.

If it's more simple to you, you can split in two parts. One while loop to read the package list file and the for loop without the first *.txt to read the files in the subfolder.